# Trying to align panels containing buttons and sudokuboards in frame

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, alignment

I have a java program that creates solutions to sudokus for me. it Then prints it to a GUI, containing the board itself and, underneath it, two labels (current solution number and total solutions) as well as a next-button. The three buttons works well enough. However, the sudokuboard gives me quite the headache. I create the boards in a method which returns a panel containing panels which symbolizes boxes, which has JLabels with the actual values.

I do get the panel to print to the GUI, but it is in one line and collapsed. Not boxes at all! 
It starts aligned above the buttons and labels, then when I press the next-button, it is moved to the top and the next sudokuboard (still in the collapsed frame) appears beneath. 
Is there something I have overlooked in my code? So far I have tried GridBagLayout, FlowLayout, GridLayout and BorderLayout. All with the same result. 
I have pasted my code beneath. Please, do ask if something is unclear.

```
JFrame frame;
JPanel sudokuPanel, buttonPanel;
GridBagConstraints c;
JLabel currentSolution, counterLabel;
JButton button;

/*
 * printSolution takes a beholder-object with all the solutions, as well as
 * the board created after reading the text-file. Then it creates the GUI
 * with help from the createSudokuPanel-method. In the
 * createSudokuPanel-method I use variables which I get from the
 * solution-objects, such as all values in the solution. the rows and
 * columns-variables are information read from the text-file, telling how
 * mant rows and columns there are in each box. the convertValue-method
 * takes a number higher than 9, up to 15, and converts it into letters
 * (A...F)
 */
public void printSolutionsGUI(final SudokuBeholder beholder, Board board) {
    frame = new JFrame();
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    final int xCoord = board.getSize();
    final int yCoord = xCoord;
    // final GridLayout gridTemp=new GridLayout(0, 1);
    // final BorderLayOut borderL = new BorderLayout
    final GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(xCoord, yCoord);
    final GridLayout bottomLineGrid = new GridLayout(1, 3);
    // GridBagLayout gridFrame = new GridBagLayout();
    // c = new GridBagConstraints();

    // xCoord + 1, yCoord
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1280, 720);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    // frame.setLayout(gridTemp);
    buttonPanel.setLayout(bottomLineGrid);
    sudokuPanel = createSudokuPanel(grid, beholder);
    // c.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    // c.gridx=0;
    // c.gridy=0;
    // c.fill=GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    // c.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    frame.add(sudokuPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    counterLabel = new JLabel("Number of solutions: " + (Integer.toString(beholder.getSolutionCount())));
    currentSolution = new JLabel("This is solution number: " + (Integer.toString(beholder.tempCount)));
    counterLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    currentSolution.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    button = new JButton("Next Solution");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.remove(sudokuPanel);
            sudokuPanel = createSudokuPanel(grid, beholder);
            frame.add(sudokuPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            currentSolution.setText("This is solution number: " + (Integer.toString(beholder.tempCount)));
        }

    });

    buttonPanel.add(counterLabel);
    buttonPanel.add(button);
    buttonPanel.add(currentSolution);
    // c.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    // c.gridx=0;
    // c.gridy=1;
    // c.gridwidth=GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

JPanel createSudokuPanel(GridLayout grid, SudokuBeholder beholder) {
    BoardSolution b = beholder.get();
    b.createBoxes();
    JPanel sudokuPanel = new JPanel();
    sudokuPanel.setLayout(grid);
    ArrayList<Box> boxList = b.getBoxList();
    JPanel[] panelArray = new JPanel[b.getSize()];

    for (int i = 0; i < b.getSize(); i++) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(grid);
        Box box = boxList.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < b.rows; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < b.columns; k++) {
                String content = Integer.toString(box.boxValuesForGUI[j][k]);
                if (Integer.parseInt(content) > 9) {
                    char c = convertValue(Integer.parseInt(content));
                    content = Integer.toString(Character.getNumericValue(c));
                }
                JLabel label = new JLabel(content);
                label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
                label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                panel.add(label);
            }
        }
        panelArray[i] = panel;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < panelArray.length; i++) {
        JPanel panel = panelArray[i];
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
        sudokuPanel.add(panel);
    }
    return sudokuPanel;
}
```

Comment: The commented-out sections are sections I do not know if I will use, but won't delete until I think out a solution. And then you can also see how I formatted the GridBagLayout.

Comment: Your code does not compile, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: For a Sudoku board use a 3x3 `Gridlayout`.

Comment: Thanks. Due to your last comment I was able to see my error, and correct it. Now I get the correct output, but the buttonPanel is very small, at the low end of the window. Any idea on how to give it more space in the GUI? I used BorderLayout in the end, with PAGE_END  as the alignment for the buttonPanel only.

Comment: Not without working code. See my first comment.